# Ninject - framework versions

Tags: .net, mono, ninject

I'm building a library that will be referenced from code that will run on Mono 4.0 and .NET Framework 4.5.  I see that Ninject ship a lib for each of these platforms: http://www.ninject.org/download.html

Is it essential that I then in turn ship two version of my lib, or is there a Ninject lib that will  run on both? I'm happy to forego any minor performance tweaks in favour of having just one version to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

The Mono builds of Ninject (among a few other things) avoid using calling internal API on `System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo`. I assume that this hack is done for performance reasons but I don't know how big the impact is.

As far as I can see there should not be a problem using the Mono builds on a .NET runtime (apart from the possible performance consequences).